# Monitoring Kafka Clusters , Producers and Consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am new to Kafka and I have three nodes Kafka cluster with multiple consumers and producers.I want to monitor the Kafka cluster on the basis of three parameters :

```
1.Topic wise monitoring - to get incoming rate of topic , lag in a topic, number of active consumers attached with the topic, number of partitions
2.Consumer based monitoring - the topic from which it is consuming,consumption speed. a number of messages consumed.
3.Message-Based Monitoring - topic name in which message is produced,and status of message i.e whether it's processed or pending.
```

I have tried various monitoring tools like (KafkaOffsetMonitor,Burrow) but none of them are matching  my use case .So can anyone suggest how to setup this kind of monitoring system?.Are there APIs available through which I can get the above-mentioned details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could fire up JConsole and monitor the whole Kafka cluster with JMX configured. See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation#monitoring for details.

Comment: Hi amethystic , Thanks for the reply but I want to store the stats somewhere so that I can have it for future references like how many consumers or producers to run. So what can I do to store the stats is there some API which give all the information as visible through Jconsole?

Comment: you have to implement your own reporter class which implments KafkaMetricsReporterMBean interface. Kafka ships with a pre-built reporter named KafkaCSVMetricsReporter which cant writes all metrics into a given csv file.

Answer (score 1):

We use two things.

- JMX metrics reported to [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/time-series-platform/influxdb/) using [jmxtrans](https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans/wiki) and visualized using [Grafana](http://grafana.org/).
- Consumer lag monitoring using [Burrow](https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow/wiki/What-is-Burrow) and reported to InfluxDB using [Burrower](https://github.com/splee/burrower)

Take a look at this [great blog about monitoring Kafka](https://softwaremill.com/monitoring-apache-kafka-with-influxdb-grafana/), most of the tools and articles about monitoring Kafka are summarized there.